# injective objects for section functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, functors

Consider a closed subset $Z$ of a topological space $X$, flabby sheaves are  injective objects for the global section functor $\Gamma_{X}$. Could someone provide a class of injectives objects relative to the functor $\Gamma_{Z}$ ? (of course independently of the abstract universal way to construct those)

Comment: Is *flabby* the same what I know as *flasque*?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen exactly

Comment: According to the book "Sheaves on Manifolds" by Kashiwara and Schapira, section 2.4, flasque sheaves are also injective with respect to $\Gamma_Z$.

Comment: @asdq it seems clear to me that if a sheaf $S$ is flabby, then $\Gamma_{Z}(S)$ is also flabby, but what you are mentioning is not clear to me, could you tell me the page or the precise section you are refering to ?

Comment: The statement is on page 101 and refers to results gathered in the previous couple of pages.

Comment: @asdq ok thank you I will check